# AngularJS Input valid if value is in array

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-validation

Having an input

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.myNumber" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I want it to be valid, if the input value is any number contained in an array (in this example the array `possibleInputValues`).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.possibleInputValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10];
});
```

So, for example, if the user types '2' into the input, it should be valid (as the array `possibleInputValues` contains 2), but should be invalid eg for the value 5.

One way i found in the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example) is to write a own directive for this kind of validation. Is this the only way or is there a more lightweighted way to do so?

What I am looking for is something like this

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.myNumber" valid-if="$ctrl.isInMyArray()"/>
```

and the controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.possibleInputValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    self.isInMyArray = function(val) {
        if (self.possibleInputValues.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
            return true
        } 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Take a look at [Angular-UI's project](https://angular-ui.github.io/) that includes a [`ui-validate` directive](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html). It may help you a lot with custom validation.

Comment: angular-ui/ui-validate lookes like it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! I will make it an answer as it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Angular-UI's project](https://angular-ui.github.io/) which includes [`ui-validate/ui-validate-async` directives](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate/master/demo/index.html).

This directives makes it very easy to create custom validator expressions. In your case it can look like `ui-validate="{inArray: 'isInMyArray($value)' }"`.